# Registering callback function in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, callback

I have a simple test function that I want the code in a DLL to callback

```
 void user_function_stats( int )
{
    cout << "Stats!\n";
}
```

So in the header file I specify a typedef

```
typedef void (CALLBACK *stats_user_function)( int );
```

and the DLL function to register the callback

```
void DLL_EXPORT getbar_client_set( stats_user_function pf );
```

which should let me register the callback function in the user code as

```
getbar_client_set(  & user_function_stats );
```

But the compiler complains

```
main.cpp|14|error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(int)' 
   to 'stats_user_function 
   {aka void (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(int)}' [-fpermissive]|
```

I have tried adding CALLBACK to the definition of the user function

```
void CALLBACK user_function_stats( int )
{
 cout << "Stats!\n";
}
```

but now I get this compiler error

```
undefined reference to `_imp__getbar_client_set'|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That token `CALLBACK` is actually a calling convention specifier of Windows. It's not necessary to use for making a callback. Windows internally merely uses a different calling convention for callbacks, rather standard C/C++ calling convention. You can do either of two things.

You could remove that `CALLBACK` token from the typedef, i.e.

```
typedef void (*stats_user_function)( int );`
```

Or you declare your callback function with the `CALLBACK` token, that expands into a `__stdcall__` calling convention specifier, i.e.

```
void CALLBACK user_function_stats( int )
{
    cout << "Stats!\n";
}
```

Comment: Same problem when I remove the CALLBACK from the typedef

Comment: @ravenspoint: Did you tell the linker, that it should actually link against the DLL? When building the DLL you should also get some `.lib` or `.a` file (depending on the compiler used) with the same name as the DLL itself. Link that with your program. This is completely unrelated to your original problem. The original problem was, that the function signatures were incompatible. Now your problem is, that your program is linked without a reference where to get the function `getbar_client_set` from.

Comment: Oops!  When I updated the DLL build it worked without CALLBACK